# What is the effect called which uses color to show events that happened in the past?

Tags: cinematography

What is the effect called which uses color to show events that happened in the past?

Attached are two screenshots from an episode of suits. Here the past has a darker maybe even orange tint. Other examples I can recall maybe used black and white, or added like a black trailing effect and or dreamy atmosphere to the shot to show events in the past.

Present:
[image]

Past:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no technical term for the visual effect used for flashbacks. However, it is sometimes referred to as [**monochrome past**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonochromePast):

> Ever since the advent of colour photography, the past has been depicted as in black and white, sepia tone or muted colors. Usually invoked for a flashback or silent film homage. Sometimes made fun of by claiming that the real world was, in fact, black and white prior to the invention of color.

Apart from black & white, sepia and other types of colour washes, [vignettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting), and [image noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise) have been used to indicate flashbacks.  These all stem from aged and/or deteriorated photo- and video film.